# Range of $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

Why don't we choose range of $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ to be $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]-\{0\}$ instead of $(0,\pi)$ so that it becomes little easier to work with arctan and arccot if they have similar range.

Comment: It's usually nicer to have a function defined and continuous on a whole interval. That being said, if it's more convenient to do it that way in a specific problem, that's fine, as long as you warn the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. Some people do, including [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcCot.html), [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/acot.html), and [MuPAD](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/arccot.html). As the latter implementation notes:

> The inverse cotangent function is multivalued. The MuPAD `arccot` function returns the value on the main branch. The branch cut is the interval $[- i, i]$ on the imaginary axis. Thus, `arccot` returns values, such that $y = \mathrm{arccot}(x)$ satisfies $-\frac\pi2<\Re(y)\leq\frac\pi2$ for any finite complex $x$.
>
> ... The values jump when the arguments cross a branch cut.
>
> ... Note: MuPAD defines `arccot` as $\mathrm{arccot}(x) = \mathrm{arctan}(1/x)$ ... As a consequence of this definition, the real line crosses the branch cut, and `arccot` has a jump discontinuity at the origin.

So your point about the ranges of arctan and arccot was important to that author. But they also felt it was important to warn the reader about the discontinuity.

There's a more complete overview of implementations here: http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/which-is-the-correct-graph-of-arccot-x-6009

Comment: Thanx I got that the problem was discontinuity.