# slant asymptote of $y=x\operatorname{arccot}(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

**help me with this problem**

*Find the slant asymptote of*

$$y=x\operatorname{arccot}(x)$$

I know that the slant asymptote is $y=ax+b$ if

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-(ax+b)=0$$

the answer given to me is:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{y}{x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\operatorname{arccot}(x)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{y}{x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\operatorname{arccot}(x)=\pi$$
$\lim_{x\to -\infty}(y-\pi x)=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arccot}(x)-\pi}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=1$(L'Hospital)

conclusion: $y=\pi x +1$ is the slant asymptote of the function

i don't understand this answer can someone explain the answer for me or have any other ways to do this problem?

note: this is from the last year exam of my college so i don't think the question is wrong, the answer was made by students though so they could be wrong.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific: which part of this solution do you not understand? I believe it would be more helpful to start with a specific explanation to a more specific question, and then take it from there.

Comment: I just don't understand how can you know that π=a

Comment: $a$ is defined by finding the limit $a=\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ if this limit exists. (And we may have to do them separately, as in this example, because they may be different.)

Answer (score -2):

Note that,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x \cot^{-1}(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ \tan^{-1}\frac1x}{\frac1x}=1$$

Thus, the asymptote $y=b=1$ is horizontal, not slant.

Edit:

The range of the inverse cotangent function is $(-\frac\pi2,0),(0,\frac\pi2)$, which does not permit a slant asymptote as $x\rightarrow -\infty$. Some source may specify its range as $(0,\pi)$, as in your answer. Then, a slant asymptote could be identified, which may be questionable.

Comment: i just added the answer can you check the answer.

Comment: @pmac - added explanation in the answer regarding the confusion.

Comment: You may be confusing the inverse cotangent function with the inverse cosecant function. Defining the range (or the principal values) of the inverse cotangent function as $(0,\pi)$ is very standard. If its range is $(-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2)$, then what is $\operatorname{arccot}(0)$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241410/range-of-arccotx

Comment: Yes, I know that the definition of each "inverse" trigonometric function is somewhat arbitrary. But then, the version that you use has the range of $(-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2]$, not $(-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2\color{red}{)}$ as in your post. However, I can't agree with calling the other choice "questionable". In most Calculus textbooks it's the preferred one.

Comment: Since it is arbitrary, it is hardly standard. Not sure $(0,\pi)$ is preferred. For instance, WA prefers otherwise.